# How to configure and enable Service Fabric Reverse Proxy for http and https?

Tags: service-fabric-stateless, service-fabric-on-premises

I want to enable localhost service fabric reverse proxy port number (19081) to be functional both for HTTP and HTTPS protocols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not be possible because the reverse proxy service is bound to a defined port in the configuration file -reverseProxyEndpointPort. The reverse proxy service can be then bound with a certificate or not. There is no ability to define more than one reverseProxyEndpoint reverse proxy service or ports.

See below example from my On-premise cluster.

```
    "nodeTypes": [
        {
            "name": "NodeType0",
            "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
            "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19001",
            "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19002",
            "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19003",
            "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
            "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "19443",
            "applicationPorts": {
                "startPort": "22222",
                "endPort": "23333"
            },
            "isPrimary": true
        }
```